# How to pass path from file to system property of my java class

Tags: java

I have a configuration file and I want to read a path to a file from config file and pass it to system properties of my java class. That's what I want to get from the file:

```
# path configuration
MyfilePATH="$projectPath/file name"
```

and that's what I have in my java class:

```
private static final String FILE_PATH = System.getProperty("FILE_PATH","DEFAULT_PATH");
```

and I uset the FILE_PATH in my java class. but since I am quite new to java I do not know how to pass the value from config file to my java class.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.getProperty will only return some specific properties : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

What you want is to read your own property file. This is described here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

The general idea will be :

```
package stack;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/absolute/path/to/your/yourconfigfile.properties");
        props.load(in);
        in.close();
        String filePath = props.getProperty("MyFilePATH", "WHATEVER-DEFAULT-VALUE-YOU WANT");
        System.out.println(filePath);
    }

}
```

However, it's not very clear what you want in your case ; what does the $projectPath thing means to you ? If you want String interpolation (replacing the $projectPath part inside the String with something else), it's a different story.

Comment: thanks for answer,  "$projectPath" is just a simple string that can be anything and does not matter. I want to retrieve the string inside the file and pass it as system property to my java class. I tried your code but in this line "props.load(in);" I see error. It says I should add cast to props. I changed to ((System) props).load(in); as suggested but did not work and I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: What can of 'cast' error message do you get ? I added the classes I'm importing, maybe you're using something else that java.util.Properties... Otherwise, I just tested it, provided you can get the File, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Properties` first to load the `config` file as shown below

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
// load a properties file
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
```

Then, to access `MyfilePATH` from the loaded properties use

```
String myPath = prop.getProperty("MyfilePATH")
```